# CSS nth-child does not work

Tags: css, css-selectors

I know this question has been asked many times but I can't figure out the problem anyway, so this is my html:

```
    <table class="UMLTable">
        <tr>
            <th>Table<th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Attribute 1<td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Attribute 1<td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Attribute 1<td>
        </tr>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

So why this line does not work:

```
.UMLTable td:nth-child(even){
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Comment: The :nth-child(n) selector matches every element that is the nth child, regardless of type, of its parent http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to select the nth `tr` element rather than the child `td` element.

Your selector should be:

```
.UMLTable tr:nth-child(even) td {
    background-color:blue;
}
```

The reason your CSS isn't working as expected is because the `td` elements aren't siblings.

```css
.UMLTable tr:nth-child(even) td {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table class="UMLTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Table
      <th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Attribute 1
      <td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Attribute 1
      <td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Attribute 1
      <td>
  </tr>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `tr` element instead of `td` like this:

```
.UMLTable tr:nth-child(even) td {
    background-color:blue;
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mL9wabjp/)**